# how to replace not supported literals inside string In Julia?

Tags: dataframe, unicode, julia

I have a vector with strings. They are names but there some spanish names who has accent.

I got something like   Benda?a ( refering to Bendaña).

I am trying to do use the uppercase function but it can't deal with literals (InvalidCharError{Char}('\xf1')

I have tried to use `replace` but with no success.

Comment: Try to create a minimal example (e.g. using Bendaña) producing the error. This will greatly help seeing how to handle it

Comment: To clarify @Rob Napier's answer: Julia's `uppercase` function works perfectly well with Spanish characters. The issue here is just that your string is not encoded properly (i.e., not in UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

Julia Strings are UTF-8 encoded. If you have a Vector or String in another encoding, you should [`transcode`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.transcode) it to convert it to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

> I got something like Benda?a ( refering to Bendaña).

Probably this means that you have a non-Unicode string, e.g. in the [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding. (`\xf1` is the Latin1 encoding of `ñ`.)

(This is separate from `transcode` and UTF-8 vs. other Unicode encodings like UTF-16 mentioned above … you have a more fundamental problem in that your data is not Unicode to begin with.)

You can use the [StringEncodings.jl package](https://github.com/JuliaStrings/StringEncodings.jl) to convert non-Unicode strings to/from Unicode.  For example:

```
julia> s = decode([0x42, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x64, 0x61, 0xf1, 0x61], "Windows-1252")
"Bendaña"

julia> uppercase(s)
"BENDAÑA"
```

(Better yet — it's 2023, you should really find an editor that lets you enter your strings in Unicode.  Some Windows editors require a configuration to use UTF-8.)